# Error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status when installing psycopg2

Tags: python, gcc, centos, odoo, centos5

I need to install `psycopg2` for `openerp` installation process, but I always faced that error. I've already used `pip` and `easy_install` and my `gcc` is the latest version. I really need your help to solve my problem.

This is my complete error with easy_install:

```
[root@server01 ~]# easy_install psycopg2    
Searching for psycopg2    
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/psycopg2/    
Reading http://initd.org/psycopg/    
Reading http://initd.org/projects/psycopg2    
Best match: psycopg2 2.4.5    
Downloading http://initd.org/psycopg/tarballs/PSYCOPG-2-4/psycopg2-2.4.5.tar.gz    
Processing psycopg2-2.4.5.tar.gz    
Running psycopg2-2.4.5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-anWVvJ/psycopg2-2.4.5/egg-dist-tmp-cZbdtn

no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build' In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
./psycopg/psycopg.h:31:22: error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:29:

...

error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 49):

You'll need to install the development package for PostgreSQL, which for instance under Ubuntu is a `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`... and for CentOS it's `yum install postgresql-devel`

Answer (score 34):

For the case of CentOS, I had this very same problem, that I solved installing these packages:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-libs
sudo yum install postgresql-devel
sudo yum install python-devel
```

only then, I was able to perform successfully:

```
sudo easy_install psycopg2
```

Comment: Thanks for not assuming that everyone uses Debian. +1

Comment: "sudo yum install python-devel" should be changed to "sudo yum install python3-devel" for python3.x

Answer (score 14):

May Your system is missing the Python headers. To fix this, run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: I searched 30 min. Installed python-psycopg2, postgresql-server-dev-9.1, postgresql-plpython-9.1 and libpq-dev. Still got '"gcc" failed with exit status 1. Now with python-dev it works fine ;-)

Comment: unless you're using CentOS

Comment: opensuse users should use: sudo zypper install python3-dev

Answer (score 14):

On a fresh ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on an EC2 instance, I was able to install psycopg2 after instaling the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install postgres-xc-server-dev
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-common
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
```

And on a fresh AMI linux (CentOS) instance:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-devel
sudo yum install gcc*
```

Hope it helps,

Erez

Answer (score 10):

i had this problem but was solved by running:

```
pip install -Iv psycopg2==2.7.7
```

There is a problem installing the latest version + python3.7

Answer (score 6):

I've been trying to install pgsql on a plain Amazon Linux EC2 instance, and have been getting this error. Per Nicolás answer, I installed his suggested list of packages, but I continued to get the error. Looking more closely at the error, I noticed that the `gcc` command was including pgsql93 files:

`gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x09030A -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/pgsql93 -I/usr/include/pgsql93/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement`

Looking in `/usr/include/` I see `pgsql92/` but not `pgsql93/`. So I took a look at what pgsql-related yum packages were installed and I noticed these:

`postgresql92.x86_64
postgresql92-devel.x86_64
postgresql92-libs.x86_64
postgresql93.x86_64
postgresql93-libs.x86_64`

Seemed to me like there ought to be a `postgresql93-devel`, so I tried:

`sudo yum install postgresql93-devel`

And that fixed the problem for me! So I guess the theme is: **Look at the gcc call, and see what dir it's pulling in**. Follow the crumbs from there.

Answer (score 5):

For `Ubuntu 14.04`, from Docker image `python:3.4.3-slim` this combination worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
sudo apt-get install -y python3.4-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libpq-dev

pip3 install psycopg2
```

Note `build-essential` package. It was crucial in my case.

Comment: Man I tried everything before this finally fixed it. Also running a docker image, so pretty much just copied your code into my dockerfile and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

In centos 7. i'd use `sudo yum install postgresql96-devel.x86_64` to solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The invocation of gcc failed, gcc couldn't compile the source. Probably the cause is

```
./psycopg/psycopg.h:31:22: error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:29:
```

that the header `libpq-fe.h` is nowhere in the search path if you have it at all.

Comment: what should i do with libpq-fe.h? 
could you give me more explanation?

Comment: Check if you have it at all. If not, install the package that provides it, `libpq-devel` or `libpq-dev` or something similar, depending on distribution.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Ubuntu Server 14.10 64-bit:

```
sudo apt-get install libpqxx-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the missing package was

```
libpqxx-devel.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

psycopg2 is also available on PyPI in the form of wheel packages for the most common platform (Linux, OSX, Windows): this should make you able to install a binary version of the module, not requiring the above build or runtime prerequisites.

**You can use this command : pip install psycopg2-binary**

Note The psycopg2-binary package is meant for beginners to start playing with Python and PostgreSQL without the need to meet the build requirements.
If you are the maintainer of a publish package depending on psycopg2 you shouldn’t use ‘psycopg2-binary’ as a module dependency. For production use you are advised to use the source distribution.

Comment: so... why am I getting " unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory" when running that command? why does it need gcc if I'm trying to install the binary version of the module?

Answer (score 0):

I was running 3.9-alpine for CICD and had to install these packages to get it working;

```
apk add postgresql-dev
apk add gcc
apk add musl-dev
```

Then I was able to run a `pip install psycopg2` as normal.