# How do I Install psycopg2 in Centos 7?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, centos7

I want to install the django backend for postgresql. I tried:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

However, I have the following output:

```
 In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:31:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
     #include <libpq-fe.h>
                          ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/_ws_/rest/gps/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-G252wf/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-CX3AAq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/_ws_/rest/gps/venv/include/site/python2.7/psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-G252wf/psycopg2/
```

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have posgres installed?

Comment: Yes I have. It's the 9.2.15 version.

Comment: see this simillar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911717/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-when-installing-psycopg2

Comment: It works now, thanks!

Comment: I used: sudo yum install postgresql-devel, this was missing. Thanks for your help!